# Django-RQ: How to call function?

Tags: python, django, redis, django-rq

I am migrating a project to `Django` and like to use the [**`django-rq`**](https://github.com/ui/django-rq) module.
However, I am stuck at what to put here:

```
import django_rq
queue = django_rq.get_queue('high')
queue.enqueue(func, foo, bar=baz)
```

How to call `func` ? Can this be a string like `path.file.function` ?
Does the function need to reside in the same file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create tasks.py file to include

```
from django_rq import job     

@job("high", timeout=600) # timeout is optional
def your_func():
     pass # do some logic
```

and then in your code

```
import django_rq
from tasks import your_func

queue = django_rq.get_queue('high')
queue.enqueue(your_func, foo, bar=baz)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Is it works only for django_rq? Because I am facing issue in this "Job object is not callable" I am using RQ only.

Refer this link [RQ](https://github.com/rq/rq)